# Question about dictionary orders for $(\mathbb{Z}_+^{\omega})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just want to make sure I understand the explanation stated below. 
According to the order relation stated below we have $(a_0,a_1,...) < (b_0,b_1,..)$ if $a_i = b_i$ for finitely many values otherwise 
$a_n < b_n$?

I also don't understand why the set X doesn't have a smallest element ?
[image]

Comment: $2,1,1,1,1,\dots\gt 1,2.1,1,1,\dots\gt 1,1,2,1,1,\dots$, and so on forever: An infinite descending chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion might lie in mis-parsing the definition: it's not 'finitely many'; it's the classic *lexicographical* order, in which we compare the two vectors element-wise until we find an index on which they disagree, and then use the natural ordering between the two values at that index.

The reason that this fails in the case you've listed is that we have $(1, 2, 1, \ldots)\lt(2, 1, 1, \ldots)$ (by comparing the first elements); but then $(1, 1, 2, 1, \ldots)\lt(1, 2, 1, 1, \ldots)$ (because the first element is the same so we compare the second); then $(1, 1, 1, 2,\ldots)\lt(1, 1, 2, 1,\ldots)$; etc, etc, etc.  There is no least element of this set because as we keep sliding the 2 'up' the vector, the elements get smaller and smaller (under the lexicographic order).

Comment: I understand. Yeah I didn't parse the definition correctly thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The set $X$ does have a smallest element, namely $(1, 1, 1, \dots )$. It's the set $A$ which has no smallest element, as follows:

Let $a = (a_1, a_2, \dots )$ be any element of $A$.  By the definition of $A$, there is some $n$ such that $a_n = 2$ and, for every $k \neq n$,  $a_k=1$.

Define $b = (b_1, b_2, \dots )$ by setting $b_{n+1} = 2$ and setting $b_k=1$ for every $k \neq n+1$.

The sequence $b$ belongs to $A$.  You can see that $a_k = b_k = 1$ for all $k<n$.  Also $b_n = 1$ and $a_n = 2$. So $b$ < $a$.

It follows that for every element $a$ of $A$, there is an element $b$ of $A$ such that $b<a$; in other words, $A$ has no least element.